# Using a WITH inside of a RECURSIVE WITH in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

In PostgreSQL, a WITH can be used by another WITH, for example:

```
WITH num AS (
    VALUES (50)
), num2 AS (
    SELECT column1 * 2 AS value FROM num
)
SELECT value FROM num2;
```

And then there are RECURSIVE WITHs, which can be done like so:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(n) AS (
    VALUES (1)
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT sum(n) FROM t;
```

But so far, I have not found a way for a RECURSIVE WITH to use a previous WITH. I would think that it should be something like this:

```
WITH num AS (
    VALUES (50)
), num2 AS (
    SELECT column1 * 2 AS value FROM num
), RECURSIVE  t(n) AS (
        VALUES (1)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < (SELECT * FROM num2)
)
SELECT sum(n) FROM t;
```

But this does not work. So is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Start with `WITH RECURSIVE`. You can still add non-recursive CTEs:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
   num (val)  AS (VALUES (50))
,  num2 (val) AS (SELECT val * 2 AS value FROM num)
,  t (n) AS (
      VALUES (1)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n+1 FROM t WHERE n < (SELECT * FROM num2)
   )
SELECT sum(n) FROM t;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bgXDWxIR)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1159)</sub>

See:

- [How to use multiple CTEs in a single SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248217/how-to-use-multiple-ctes-in-a-single-sql-query/35249370#35249370)

Comment: Nice! I always thought the order would matter, but doesn't seem to matter that much after all...